# A Type.FromText function in M for PowerQuery using Expression.Evaluate

Tags: excel, m-code, powerquery-m

## The Solution

I recently came across this solution [here](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2019/11/17/dynamically-create-types-from-text-with-type-fromtext), for a `Type.FromText()` function in M for Power Query*.  This solution allows a user to extract the actual `type` itself of a column, as *named* (`text`ually) in the `TypeName` column generated by [`Table.Schema()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-schema).

It struck me that there is a solution far simpler than listing out *literally every `type` in M*, and that this new solution would be dynamic enough to accommodate

- types like `Int64.Type` omitted from the original solution;
- custom `type`s defined by the user; **and**
- new `type`s introduced into the M language in the future.

After a little research [here](https://ssbi-blog.de/blog/technical-topics-english/the-environment-concept-in-m-for-power-query-and-power-bi-desktop-part-3/), I leveraged [`Expression.Evaluate()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/expression-evaluate) in tandem with the `#shared` (ie. global) environment, as follows:

```
let TypeFromText = (TypeAsText as text) =>
  Expression.Evaluate(TypeAsText, #shared)
  // ...
in
  // ...
```

This worked fine when I tested `TypeFromText()` in several complex operations within Power Query. Naturally, in any situation where the native type is globally available, this solution will work without fail.

## The Danger

I'm worried about naming collisions.  Is it possible for a user to define a variable named `Int64.Type`, that will mask the native `Int64.Type` in the `#shared` environment?

Also, how might one dynamically restrict the possible input for `TypeAsText`, to ensure no other "live" code is "injected" and executed?  Keep in mind that the set of `type`s may change, so a static "lookup" table defeats the entire dynamic purpose.  Also note that a test like

```
Value.Type(Expression.Evaluate(TypeAsText, #shared)) = Type.Type
```

could only be evaluated *after* the "injected" code has been executed.

**How might I stabilize this function against future failures?**